# Splitting a space separated list

Tags: java, string

This is a common task I'm facing: splitting a space separated list into a *head* element and an array containing the *tail* elements. For example, given this string:

```
the quick brown fox
```

We want:

```
"the"
["quick","brown","fox"]
```

.. in two different variables. The first variable should be a string, and the second an array. I'm looking for an **elegant** way to do this (preferably in Java).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For certain values of elegant:

```
String input = "The quick brown fox";
String[] elements = input.split(" ");
String first = elements[0];
String[] trailing = Arrays.copyOfRange(elements,1,elements.length);
```

I can't think of a way to do it with less code...

Comment: `Arrays.copyOfRange()` - wow, thanks, I learn something new every day from other peoples' answers!

Comment: If the user intends to "pop" one item out of the String[] array, then Lists would be better, right?  (I'm thinking after they get the above solution working, they might realize that).

Answer (score 9):

The most elegant is probably to use `String.split` to get a `String[]`, then using `Arrays.asList` to turn it into a `List<String>`. If you really need a separate list minus the head, just use `List.subList`.

```
    String text = "the quick brown fox";
    List<String> tokens = Arrays.asList(text.split("\\s+"));

    String head = tokens.get(0);
    List<String> body = tokens.subList(1, tokens.size());

    System.out.println(head); // "the"
    System.out.println(body); // "[quick, brown, fox]"

    System.out.println(body.contains("fox")); // "true"
    System.out.println(body.contains("chicken")); // "false"
```

Using a `List` allows you to take advantage of the rich features provided by Java Collections Framework.

#### See also

- *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 25: Prefer lists to arrays*
- [Java Lessons/Introductions to Collections](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html)

Comment: Even though this is slightly more code than my `Arrays.copyOfRange()` solution, I think yours probably wins on elegance, unless the asker needs blazing speed or is in a very low-memory environment (in which case why on earth is he/she using Java?)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you get most of what you want with

```
String[] pieces = "how now brown cow".split("\\s")
```

or so. Your result will be an array of Strings.

If you really, really want the first item separate from the rest, you can then do something like:

```
String head = pieces[0];
String[] tail = new String[pieces.length - 1];
System.arraycopy(pieces, 1, tail, 0, tail.length);
```

...done.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of [`String#split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) taking a limit as 2nd argument.

```
String text = "the quick brown fox";
String[] parts = text.split(" ", 2);
String headPart = parts[0];
String[] bodyParts = parts[1].split(" ");

System.out.println(headPart); // the
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bodyParts)); // [quick, brown, fox]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package playground;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class TokenizerTest extends TestCase {

    public void testTokenize() throws Exception {
        String s = "the quick brown fox";
        MyThing t = new MyThing(s);
        assertEquals("the", t.head);
        String[] rest = {"quick", "brown", "fox"};
        assertEqualArrays(rest, t.rest);
    }

    private static void assertEqualArrays(String[] a, String[] b) {
        assertEquals(a.length, b.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
            assertEquals(a[i], b[i]);
    }

    private static class MyThing {
        private final String head;
        private final String[] rest;

        public MyThing(String s) {
            String[] array = s.split(" ");
            head = array[0];
            rest = new String[array.length - 1];
            System.arraycopy(array, 1, rest, 0, array.length - 1);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "the quick brown fox";
        int indexOf = s.indexOf(' ');
        String head = s.substring(0, indexOf);
        String[] tail = s.substring(indexOf + 1).split(" +");
        System.out.println(head + " : " + Arrays.asList(tail));
    }
```

Would have been much easier in Haskell :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [StringTokenizer](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) and a while loop to step through each element.  Inside the loop, you can get the first element and put the rest into an array.

Edit: Oh, I guess StringTokenizer is a "legacy" class (though it still works).

The recommended way is now to use [String.split()](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).  That will give you a String[] containing your elements.  From there it should be trivial to get the first element and also create an array out of the remaining elements.

Comment: Hmm. Problem is, you can't really know how many tokens there are other than calling nextToken until there's no more tokens. So you can't really allocate an array and put it in?

Comment: That's correct, since arrays are immutable, you'd have to use System.arraycopy.  But it's a moot point since it'd be better to use split() as others described.

Answer (score 0):

```
str= "the quick brown fox"
  pqr = str.split(" ")
```